# How to call a payment gateway within the app?

Tags: android, payment-gateway, android-webview

My app is a simple booking system which enables users to pay from their credit cards. (This app is a module of a already finished web application)

Question is How to call a payment gateway within the app?

Is it possible to access the services from the existing web application and proceed with the payment?
OR
Is is advisable to use a webview with the URL of the existing web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Through this link https://www.x.com/community/ppx/xspaces/mobile. you can get mobile payment libraries for Android and as well as for iPhone.

it also contains sample code. You can use this code into your apps and modify it as your project requirement.

Comment: this seems quite interesting.. I will try to use it. Thanks

Comment: sukitha, I think you need to share your experience with extra effort you need to pure..